# jQuery Selector for Section that Contains Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to display all of the fields within the section when the h2 element within that section is clicked. Example: when a user clicks 'Contact Information' the 3 form inputs (fields) below the Contact Information heading are shown.

All of my form fields are hidden with the following css:

```
div.field {
  display:none;
}
```

Here's the jQuery that I'm using for that:

```
$('section > h2').click(function(){
  $('.field').toggle();
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<section>
  <h2>Contact Information</h2>
  <div class="field>
    // form input
  </div>
  <div class="field>
    // form input
  </div>
  <div class="field>
    // form input
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Address</h2>
  <div class="field>
    // form input
  </div>
  <div class="field>
    // form input
  </div>
  <div class="field>
    // form input
  </div>
</section>
```

What happens here is that all of the fields are shown - not just the ones within the same section as the h2 that is being clicked. How can I toggle visibility of only the fields within the same section as the h2 that is being clicked?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go back up to the section, then find all the `.field` elements within that specific section

```js
$('section > h2').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('section').find('.field').toggle();
});
```

```css
div.field {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h2>Contact Information</h2>
  <div class="field">
    form input 1
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    form input 2
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    form input 3
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Address</h2>
  <div class="field">
    form input 4
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    form input 5
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    form input 6
  </div>
</section>
```

As long as you keep the HTML just as it is, `siblings` would work as well

```
$(this).siblings('.field').toggle()
```

but it's more specific, and won't work with nested elements

Comment: siblings() is exactly the function that I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('section > h2').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.field').toggle();
});
```

```css
div.field {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h2>Contact Information</h2>
  <div class="field">
    // form input
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    // form input
  </div>
  <div class="field">
     //form input
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Address</h2>
  <div class="field">
    // form input
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    // form input
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    // form input
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your field divs come after the h2 element you can use [.nextAll('.field')](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```js
$('section > h2').click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll('.field').toggle();
});
```

```css
div.field {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section>
    <h2>Contact Information</h2>

    <div class="field">
        // form input
    </div>
  <div class="field">
      // form input
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        // form input
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Address</h2>
  <div class=" field">
      // form input
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    // form input
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      // form input
    </div>
</section>
```